# Is Russia generations ahead in hypersonic missile development?

Tags: military, russia

According to a news article on Russia Today, Russia is leading the US in hypersonic missile development by generations:

> The bottom line is that Russia – in terms of hypersonic missile development – is about four generations ahead of the US, if we measure it by the development of the S-300, S-400 and S-500 systems. As a working hypothesis, we could describe the next system – already in the drawing boards – as the S-600. It would take the US military at least ten years to develop and roll out a new weapons system, which in military terms represents a generation.

https://www.rt.com/op-edge/344002-beware-russia-war-us/

Does it warrant credence of their conclusion, Russia being immune to (conventional) military retaliation?

> The key fact of the matter needs to be stressed over and over again; the S-500 is impenetrable - and allows Russia for the first time in history to launch a first strike nuclear attack, if it ever chooses to do so, and be immune to retaliation.

Comment: Those are some grandiose claims, even for Russia's state media.

Comment: tbh all you need to get through any missile defense is enough missiles. If all they have is N air-intercept missiles available to launch, so long as you have N+1 ballistic missiles, you win.

Comment: If the sole objective is to get a missile through, yes, you'd win. You made your point though, an arms race is not just a technological one but a numerical one too; there is a strength in numbers.

Comment: Railguns and lasers may make this new missile-gap irrelevant.

Comment: Not to mention that [truth is a casualty of cold wars, too.](http://satwcomic.com/cold-war-games)